# Presenting form errors without embedding php

Tags: php, mysql, json, forms

I have been working on some sample exercises for a future employer and I was recently tasked with what was essentially my first ever go at writing php. Part of the assignment involved keeping the server side code separate from the UI code, which I totally understand the value of and I'm on board with it.

The gist of the assignment was to create a simple form that posted to the server, validated, and posted to a database, there were quite a few other tasks and things involved, but this is pretty much what it really was.

So I couldn't quite determine the best way to present the form validation errors back to the user. I ended up going with a session and redirecting the user back to the form which seemed to be what most people suggested. I then printed back the submitted data from `$_SESSION` to the user inside the `value` attributes of the form's `input` elements as well as creating some additional elements if there were errors present.

I was told this wasn't what he wanted and he briefly mentioned creating an API with PHP and MySQL that returned JSON data through Ajax calls. I understand that for fetching data from the database and serving back JSON.

In this case, when the assignment does not actually require fetching data stored in the database, just inserting new data, would you then send back the errors and the contents of the form's fields as JSON instead of using `$_SESSION`?

Comment: For _validation_ of input data they want you to store that data into a database first, to present it back to the user when it has _failed_ validation? Makes little sense (in general at least, unless one would want to log customer input for analysis even if it was invalid – but if that wasn’t asked for …)

Comment: Yeah, so I skipped over client side validation (well, used html5, but assuming that fails or someone bypasses it maliciously) - the server checks for required/empty/valid email and phone patterns, if any of those come back as invalid, I want to display that to the user on the form and also repopulate the form with the data they submitted. I did it with $_SESSION, but that involved embedding fragments of php into the html, is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Well you can send the data to the server via AJAX, and then get a JSON data structure back that contains the error messages for different field … but I see little advantage in that, because unless its very special validation that HTML5 can’t handle, it should have happened client-side without JS already. Makes more sense then IMHO to send the form normally, and output the form again in case of validation errors, with messages in appropriate places – that way, you handle not only clients that can’t do HTML5 validation, but those that won’t to JS/AJAX as well …

Comment: Of course that would require a _certain_ amount of mixing of PHP script logic and generation of the form – but to keep those two separated, that’s what templates are for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Ajax does not imply working with database. Any error validation can be done server-side using ajax request.

For example if you have a form that submits a value which can contain only letters for example , assuming that you have the following form:

```
<span id="error" style="display:none;color:red;"></span>
<form id="myform" action="submit.php" method="POST">
  <input name="mystring" type="text" placeholder="your text here"><br>
  <button id="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

and your **validate.php** looks like this:

```
<?php>
 echo json_encode(array(
                  "success"=>(ereg("^[a-zA-Z]+$", $_POST['mystring']),
                  "error"=>"This field must contain only letters"
                 ));
?>
```

then your ajax request should look something like this (using jQuery):

```
$("#submit").click(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "validate.php",

    success: function(response, status) {
      if(response.success) {
        $("#myform").submit();
      }
      else {
        $("#error").html(response.error).show();            
      }
    }
  });
});
```

How does this work?

When you click on the submit button the onclick event fires this part of the code:
`$("#submit").click(function() {`

An ajax request is made to **validate.php** which accepts the field value and checks with regex to see if it contains only letters. The result of `ereg("^[a-zA-Z]+$", $_POST['mystring'])` is either true or false. If it's true then we assume that the string contains only letters. [json_encode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) converts arrays to JSON strings, so you have to put the regex result into an array. Then you have to echo it to create a blank page and 
return it to the browser. jQuery captures the response and assuming that the response is a valid JSON string tries to parse it and create a javascript object. Then this object is being passed to the success callback function. Which is called **response** in our case.
Next you check the value of **success** property of the **response** object. If it's true we submit the form, if not we show an error message.

Comment: This is pretty much what I was thinking I would have to do - have an intermediate step that validates and returns JSON. I will try this out